# P(X<Y) given joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

I am given the joint density function $f(x,y)$ for random variables X,Y with $0<x<1$, $0<y<2$
I am interested in $P(X<Y)$

My first instinct was to do the following:
$$P(X<Y) = \int_0^2\int_0^yf(x,y)dxdy$$
but this cannot be correct since we are integrating for values of y between 1 and 2 when x can never achieve those values.
So I think it should be the following:
$$P(X<Y) = (\int_0^1\int_0^yf(x,y)dxdy)+ P(Y>1)$$
Is this correct?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not both?  Both are right!

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y) &= \int_0^2\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y \\[1ex] &= \int_0^1\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y + \int_1^2\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&= \int_0^1\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y + \mathsf P(Y>1) 
\end{align}$$

---

Because $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ equals $0$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can proceed as follows

$P(X<Y)=E(1_{X<Y})=\int_{x<y} f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \int_{-\infty}^y dx\ f(x,y).$ Now you can substitute the value of $f(x, y)$ and evaluate the integral.

Comment: Notice you will have $f(x, y) = 0$ for $x$ or $y$ outside the prescribed range.